# How i can change algorithm to get better asymptotic complexity?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, python-3.x

guys.

I have an algo with a good timing, i should change it to get better time, but i have no any idea.

Can u help me?

Here is time:

- real 0m0.164s
- user 0m0.021s
- sys  0m0.010s

Here is algo:

```
def algo2(A, B):
    x=0
    y=0
    for a in A:
          m=0
          for b in B:
                if a == b:
                      m += 1
          if m>y:
                x = a
                y = m
    return x;
```

Here is arrays for algo:
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,4,7,8,9,0]

Comment: Is there a bound on the values in the arrays? Are the arrays always sorted?

Comment: What does the algorithm do?

Comment: I guess elements in A are unique, but not in B. You want to find the element in A occurring the most often in B. With n the number of elements in A and m the number of elements in B, you algorithm is in O(nm). A way to get a better big O would be to sort A and B and then linearly browse A and B resulting in a O(n.log n + m.log m + n + m)

Comment: No bounds, not sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is O(n*m). If the arrays are always sorted, you can do a straight merge (O(n+m)), as below. (Note that the code is not python ... I think you can get the idea and translate it)

```
ixA = 0
ixB = 0
maxVal = 0
maxCount = 0
workingVal = A[ixA]
workingCount = 0
while (ixA < A.length and ixB < B.length)
{
    if (workingVal == B[ixB])
    {
        workingCount += 1
    }
    else if (workingCount > maxCount)
    {
        maxCount = workingCount
        maxVal = workingVal
        workingCount = 0
        ixA += 1
        workingVal = A[ixA]
    }
    ixB += 1
}
// have to check the last one
if (workingCount > maxCount)
{
    maxCount = workingCount
    maxVal = workingVal
}
```

If the arrays aren't sorted, you can sort them first, then do the merge. That will be O(m log m) + O(n log n) + O(m+n). That's still better than your O(m*n).